# Rituals to be followed on confirmation of legal divorce

Tags: rituals

What are the rituals to be followed by a girl who has recently obtained legal divorce?

Comment: There's no divorce in Vedic system, but ladies has remarried after husband died in war or something like that or else when husband choose Sanyasa.

Answer (score 2):

Hinduism does not recognize the modern notion and concept of the legal divorce.

So, there are no rituals, because divorce is an alien concept.

Manusmṛti says -

> [Verse 9.47](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201406.html)
>
> सकृदंशो निपतति **सकृत् कन्या प्रदीयते** ।
> सकृदाह ददानीति **त्रीण्येतानि सतां
> सकृत्** ॥ ४७ ॥
>
> > 47. Once does the share fall to a man; **once is a maiden given away**; once does one say ‘I give’; **each of these three comes only once.**

Almost all the canonical scriptures concur on this 'doctrine of only one marriage for a women', except in the cases of some exceptional exceptions (for instance, cf. [Agni Purāṇa 154. 3-6](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083384.html)).

Comment: there is a concept of living sraddham though. where husband/wife do the apara karyam as if the other one is dead to them. this is in those 'exception' cases you mentioned - where husband dies, abandons, renounces a virgin wife.